# Is it possible to use a variable to replace a reference

Tags: ios, swift

VC1 has three buttons 'Card1', 'Card2', and 'Card3', each segues to VC2 which has four buttons with Images '2s', '2h', '2c' and '2d'

segue.identifiers are Card1, Card2, Card3

buttons '2s', '2h', '2c' and '2d' all unwind segue and should replace original segue-caller button image with image from Images.xcassets named: '2s', '2h', '2c' or '2d' according to which button selected in VC2

**CardSelected** identifies which VC2 button called unwindSegue.

and unwind segue-identifiers are 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively with a 5th "clear button segue-identifier as 0.

images are declared in array Cards (VC1) and unwindSegue-identifier is used to call the index.

**Is it possible to consolidate this code...**

**EDIT FULL CODE AS IS**

VC1

```
import UIKit

class VC1: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Card1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Card2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Card3: UIButton!

let Cards: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Default")!, UIImage(named: "2s")!,UIImage(named: "2h")!,UIImage(named: "2c")!,UIImage(named: "2d")!,]

var caller = ""
var Index2 = Int()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let KVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
    KVC.source = segue.identifier!}

@IBAction func unwind(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    Card1.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    //I want to replace Card1.setImage with (UIButton with name = "caller").setImage
    //instead of having
    //if caller = "Card1" {Card1.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)} else if caller = "Card2" {Card2.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)} else if caller = "Card3" {Card3.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)}
}

@IBAction func text(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(caller)
    println(Index2)
}
```

}

VC2

```
import UIKit

class VC2: UIViewController {

var CardSelected = ""
var source = ""

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    CardSelected = segue.identifier!
    var Index:Int = CardSelected.toInt()!
    let DVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC1
    DVC.caller = source
    DVC.Index2 = Index

}
}
```

**In VC1, I want to somehow make Card1.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal) as (X).setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal) where (X) is replaced at code with current 'caller'**

I thought to place UIButtons in an array and call it from the array but

```
let CardCaller: [UIButton] = [UIButton(Card1)!, UIButton(Card2)!, UIButton(Card3)!]  //in VC1
```

brings error: 'VC1.Type' does not have a member named 'Card1'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955620/array-of-uibuttons-or-method-uibuttonnamed-string

Using Array to decide the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Make `cards` a dictionary within your destinationViewController.

```
var CardPicked = String()
var sourceMessage : NSString = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cards = [String: String]()
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Back" {

    } else {
        CardPicked = segue.identifier!
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
        dvc.cards[sourceMessage] = CardPicked
    }
}
```

Comment: As is I get "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0).   Do i have to fill in var cards = [String: String]() with all possible  "F1Card"..."F23Card" etc?

Comment: Or do i have to make DVC a subclass of ViewController (which is my VC1's name)?

Comment: Use ViewController and add the cards to ViewController. DVC was just a placeholder. You should add all the cards to the cards array.

Comment: I have..  Class ViewController: UIViewController { var cards = ["F1Card", "F2Card"]...AS TO line.  dvc.cards[sourceMessage] = CardPicked (Error NSString is Not convertible to 'int')

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke. You need a dictionary here: `["F1Card": "", "F2Card": ""]`

Comment: I'm still getting the "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT.....ETC Error. I am editing original post to show full code as is.

Comment: First of all take `ViewController` outside of `FlopViewController`--there's no reason it needs to be a nested class. Second, you're missing the closing bracket on `FlopViewController`

Comment: Took nested class out, no longer error...bracket is there just got cut off in paste... But now cards do not load image.

Comment: The way dvc.cards[sourceMessage] seems to need to work I have in VC1 var cards = ["F1Card": F1Card] since souceMessage is a NSString=segue.identifier and the cards[sourceMessage] needs to = F1Card (NSString var declared in VC1...but i get error that 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'cards'

Comment: When you retrieve from a dictionary you're getting back an optional. You need to unwrap your optionals. So, if you're trying to create a named image: `UIImage(named: cards['FIImage']!)! `. Is there any reason you're using `NSString` instead of `String`?

Comment: Um..when i used elongated code, string wasn't passing between VC's and NSString seemed to work. Im new to coding but understood they are compatible. As to UIImage(named: cards['FIImage']!)! , my original unwindToSegue (VC1) works with elongated code "wrapped" (unfamiliar with optionals) the issue seems to be 1)proper format for 'cards' dictionary and dvc.cards[sourceMessage]

Comment: Your original code sequence worked because you weren't pulling the cards from a dictionary. An `optional` means that a value might be `nil`. Whenever you select something from a dictionary there's a possibility that it might not be there, so you have to 'unwrap' or add an exclamation to get the real value

Comment: ok but F1image is a var created and not connected to the dictionary... so do i have to do this to the dvc.cards[sourceMessage] as dvc.cards[sourceMessage]!    ?

Comment: you don't want to make F1image a variable in its own right--just set it up in the dictionary.

Comment: I am thoroughly confused now...editing OP to simplify

Comment: I think I figured out a work-around if i can find out how to do..    IBAction func unwind(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        (X).setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }    where (X) is IBOutlet weak var (X): UIButton! but var caller = "" is used to set (X)