# Array of UIButtons or method UIButton(named: "\(string)")

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to make an array of `UIButton`s?

```
let buttonArray: [UIButton] = [UIButton(Button1)!, UIButton(Button2)!, UIButton(Button3)!]
```

To reference later as

```
buttonArray[0].setImage(UIImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Or somehow set a

```
var button = UIButton.whoseName = "Specific String"
button.setImage(UIImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

VC1:

```
import UIKit

class VC1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Card1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Card2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Card3: UIButton!
    let Cards: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Default")!, UIImage(named: "2s")!,UIImage(named: "2h")!,UIImage(named: "2c")!,UIImage(named: "2d")!,]
    // var CardCaller: Array<UIButton> = [Card1, Card2, Card3]
    let CardCallers: [UIButton] = [Card1, Card2, Card3]  //ERROR: 'VC1.Type' does not have a member named 'Card1'
    var caller = ""
    var Index2 = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let KVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
        KVC.source = segue.identifier!


    }
    @IBAction func unwind(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        //Card1.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //let button = UIButton(named: "Card1")!
        if caller == "Card1" {Card1.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)} else if caller == "Card2" {Card2.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)} else if caller == "Card3" {Card3.setImage(Cards[Index2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)}
    }

    @IBAction func text(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(caller)
        println(Index2)
    }

}
```

The `IBOutlets` are wired properly to Storyboard buttons; I created them with control/drag to the view controller.

Comment: It's certainly possible; are you running into any specific errors?

Comment: @AstroCB I'm getting error 'VC1.Type' does not have a member named 'Button1' even though IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton! is declared in VC1

Comment: If it's already declared as a UIButton, then you don't need to wrap it as one. Just do this: `let buttonArray: [UIButton] = [Button1, Button2, Button3]`.

Comment: declared as a UIButton means...@IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!...right?

Comment: Yes; your button has already been set to type `UIButton` and it has been "created" by the time your array is initialized, if you want to think of it like that.

Comment: so yes I have declared the buttons as IBOutlets but still get 'VC1.Type' does not have a member named 'Button1'

Comment: I'm assuming `VC1` is the name of your view controller; in that case, you may not have correctly wired your IBOutlets to your Storyboard buttons.

Comment: the IBOutlets are control/drag created from the storyboard buttons, and I can reference them fine later on in VC1

Comment: That's weird; where are you creating this array?

Comment: included VC1 code in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem, but it may have something to do with when you're accessing the buttons. Try creating the array globally and adding the buttons to it once they've loaded:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Card1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Card2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Card3: UIButton!
    var CardCallers: [UIButton] = [UIButton]() // Empty UIButton array

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.CardCallers = [self.Card1, self.Card2, self.Card3] // Buttons have now loaded in the view
    }
}
```

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        buttons = [Card1, Card2, Card3]
    } produces error 'Cannot assign to 'buttons' in 'self''

Comment: ty, had to set var, not let and adding self.blah worked...btw how do i input 'UIButtons' in my text as grey-boxed, like how you edited my OP?

Comment: @Dustin I'm glad I could help; you just enclose the parts you want as code with backticks ( \` ).

Answer (score 0):

You can.

Two ways to do it:

```
var buttonsArray: Array<UIButton> = [button1, button2]
```

Or

```
@IBOutlet var buttonsArray: Array<UIButton> = []
```

For the later one, it can be filled from the storyboard as an `IBOutletCollection`

Please note that views can be assigned to an `IBOutlet` and an `IBOutletCollection` at the same time.

Comment: I still get error 'VC1.Type' does not have a member named 'Button1'

Comment: @Dustin How do you declare Button1 ?